# Define order without imposing dependency in GNU Make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want phony `clean` target is always executed before `build` target but nothing else (like `build` target does not trigger `clean`).

I know solutions that don't rely on GNU Make language:

- Launch them sequentially when order is needed:

```
make clean
make build
```

- Encode sequential execution into required recipes:

```
.PHONY: install
install:
    $(MAKE) clean
    $(MAKE) build
```

Above "workarounds" suffer from being non-generic. I have to remember not to run `make clean build`!

My question is about *expressive power of GNU Make language*, **if it is possible to define order without imposing dependency**.

Other build systems have optional dependency declaration obeying order, like Gradle's `mustRunAfter`.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [order only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types).

Comment: @G.M. No, order-only imposes hard dependency, I only need order. Order-only is for directories when you don't care about timestamps. I am afraid it is impossible to express order without imposing dependency in GNU Make. May be there is some hack with `.NOTPARALLEL`, who knows...

Comment: There is no better way to do it than the ones you've given.  In fact, even if there were such a thing it couldn't work the way you suggest: make uses a _depth-first_ search of targets so even if there were a way to say "if both targets need to be built, this one must come first", you'd have to put that relationship on _all_ the targets (all the .o files, etc.) not just on the top-most **build** target.

Comment: Can you put this in context for us?  What's the actual situation you're trying to solve for?

Comment: @MadScientist You could dynamically add the `clean` target to `.EXTRA_PREREQS` to do that, no?

Comment: Oh, right.  I forgot about that.  Yes, if you're sure that you have GNU make 4.3 or better you can use `.EXTRA_PREREQS`: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html#Special-Variables  However, note that these prerequisites are definitely considered when computing out-of-date-ness so adding a `.PHONY` target there is a little odd.  For a `clean` target that might be OK since you'll probably want to rebuild everything anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there is a way to do what I think you want to do, but note my caveat above about depth-first order.

Your question is not completely clear but I think what you want to say is, if the user asked for both `clean` and `build` on the command line be sure that `clean` is performed first before `build`.

You can do this like:

```
build: $(filter clean,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
```

This will cause `build` to depend on `clean` IFF `clean` was specified as one of the command-line goals to build.

However note my comment above: this won't be enough if you invoke make with parallelism enabled, because it will not realize that all the object files etc. ALSO must wait for `clean` to complete.  In order to make this really foolproof you'd have to add this prerequisite to *EVERY* target.

Comment: Yes, parallelization breaks everything... Seems Make is a file dependency engine, not a general / expressive task dependency management engine.

Comment: If by that you mean, make doesn't have any grouping capabilities then that's true.  Each individual target in a makefile is considered a solitary element and there is no way to create a "group" of targets then declare prerequisites of the entire group with one declaration.  If you want a prerequisite on a set of targets you have to declare that prerequisite individually on each one.  Or, use recursive invocations of make to provide you with some "grouping".

Answer (score 1):

> I have to remember not to run make clean build!

You could test the `MAKECMDGOALS` variable for presence of both `clean` and `build`, then throw error if they are both in there:

```
ifeq (clean, $(filter clean, $(MAKECMDGOALS)))
  ifeq (build, $(filter build, $(MAKECMDGOALS)))
    $(error Cannot have clean and build goals at the same time)
  endif  
endif
```

Comment: Working on the problem yersterday I wrote mostly exact code independently: http://hg.defun.work/dot-emacs/file/tip/Makefile Instead of `ifeq something` I use `ifneq ''` (not-empty check) to reduce duplication. It shows that users of GNU Make like-minded ))